# Faulty reversing array in assembly

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, intel

Ah well I want to make procedure that reverses array
so I made this

```
        section .data
    rev:
        push eax
        push ebx
        push esi
        push ecx
        mov ebx,ecx
        mov eax,esi
        Lrev_1:
            push dword[esi]
            inc esi
            loop Lrev_1
        mov ecx,ebx
        Lrev_2:
            pop dword[eax]
            inc eax
            loop Lrev_2
        pop ecx
        pop esi
        pop ebx
        pop eax
        ret
    msg dd "Hello"
section .text
global _start
_start:
    mov esi,msg
    mov ecx,5
    call rev
    mov eax,4
    mov ebx,1
    mov ecx,msg
    mov edx,5
    int 80h
    mov eax,1
    xor ebx,ebx
    int 80h
```

And It perfectly works fine but as you can see I made it to push all the contents of memory address to stack which can be slow (like turtle)

So I try to use [this way](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/write-a-program-to-reverse-an-array-or-string/)

And then I implemented it as I can into these 3 ways

```
section .data
    rev1:
        push eax
        push ebx
        push esi
        push edi
        Lrev1:
            cmp esi,edi
            jge Lrev1_out
            mov eax,dword[esi]
            mov ebx,dword[edi]
            mov dword[esi],ebx
            mov dword[edi],eax
            inc esi
            dec edi
            jmp Lrev1
        Lrev1_out:
        pop edi
        pop esi
        pop ebx
        pop eax
        ret
    rev2:
        push esi
        push edi
        Lrev2:
            cmp esi,edi
            jge Lrev2_out
            push dword[esi]
            push dword[edi]
            pop dword[esi]
            pop dword[edi]
        pop edi
        pop esi
        ret
    rev3:
        push eax
        push esi
        push edi
        Lrev3:
            cmp esi,edi
            jge Lrev3_out
            mov eax,dword[esi]
            xchg eax,dword[edi]
            mov dword[esi],eax
            inc esi
            dec edi
            jmp Lrev3
        Lrev3_out:
        pop edi
        pop esi
        pop eax
        ret
    msg dd "Hello"
section .text
global _start
_start:
    mov esi,msg
    mov edi,esi
    add edi,4
    ;if I call rev1 or rev2 here msg will be reverse into oH for me
    ;if I call rev3 here msg will be reversed into oHel for me
    mov eax,4
    mov ebx,1
    mov ecx,msg
    mov edx,5
    int 80h
    mov eax,1
    xor ebx,ebx
    int 80h
```

Well, My expected result is olleH.But then I got the unexpected result.
Did I miss something? Or just added something even more?
to get the true reversed result

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow.  My first thought is to compile your "good" C code and read its assembler and compare it to what you expect.  I bet you will get a few ideas on how better to implement your swap this way.  My second is to have you step through your asm in GDB or some similar debugger and see where it goes wrong.  I am willing to bet that you are messing up your indexing from the looks of the output.

Comment: Your expected result is "olleH" and I can guess what your input was. But what *did* you get?

Comment: @MichaelDorgan 
Um Perhaps

Comment: @usr2564301 
I already typed in the code perhaps my mistake ah
if I call rev1 or rev2 result will be oH
but if I call rev3 result will be oHel

Comment: You can use [edit] to add all relevant data to your question. You may want to read the [tour] and [ask] some time.

Comment: @usr2564301 Ah but It's already added
Just look at semicolon line in that code

Comment: Don't put your code in the `.data` section.  On some systems, it will be mapped into a non-executable page.  Also, if you want to put the details of what you do get only in a comment, at least *say* that in the text.  People read the text first before deciding if it's worth even looking at the code carefully, and this looks like it's missing important info to make it a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to reverse bytes that you load as 32 bit double words instead.

Maybe this will help for rev1?

```
        mov al,[esi]
        mov bl,[edi]
        mov [esi],bl
        mov [edi],al
```

You have similar problems in rev2 and rev3. Also `XCHG` with memory has implications far beyond just exchanging reg<->mem... I'd be careful with that instruction.

Comment: So I need to use 8 bits size
whether I want to reverse as 32 bits?

Comment: Your strings use characters, not 32 bit words, right? You could use a special algorithm if the string is an exact multiple of 4 bytes in length using the `swapb` instruction to swap the bytes in the registers before saving them back to memory. Other it won't work. You could also run in alignment problems using 32 bits, although most systems will accept access starting at any byte.

Comment: The "memory implications" of `xchg` are only for performance, not correctness.  But it is a *big* performance difference, probably at least 10x.

Comment: @AlexisWilke 
I think It is bswap...
anyway thanks!
for made me more understood :D
really really appreciate T^T

Comment: @user9241513 Ah! Yes `bswap`. Next you'll want to look into swapping a UTF-8 string. Ha! Ha!